# Broken disk head

Tags: algorithms, markov-chains

Broken disk head:

We would like to read 1 byte = sequence of 8 bits from a disk, starting from bit 0.
Our disk head reads 1 bit at a time.

Disk head can only move forward, but after reaching bit 7 it starts from 0 again.

One head action (reading or moving) lasts 1 milisecond;

Unfortunately, disk head is severely broken:
1. it reads 1 bit correctly from its position with a probability of r, otherwise reads nothing;
2. it moves over next bit with a probability of m, otherwise stays at the same place.

Consider such nondeterministic algorithm A1 for reading 1 byte from disk:
1. Take $x$;
2. With a probability of $x$, try to read current bit;
3. With a probability of $1-x$, try to move forward;

> Task:
>
> For fixed values $r,m,x$:
>   estimate the average time of reading 1 byte from disk using algorithm A1.
>
> Hint: Markov chain

Can anyone tell me how to start solving this?
Markov chains are still a bit ambiguous to me,
some general pattern would be very helpful...